# LINQ : ASP.NET EntityDataSource Beginner's Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-sql, entitydatasource

I am new to ASP.NET and have some questions about syntax...
I have several SQL DB Tables that hold information about ride_reservations, vehicles, and admin options. This is for an asp.net program feature that will select the next best ride reservation to send to a certain vehicle.

I am attempting to begin (and figure out syntax) by populating a C# ArrayList with the rides in the db that are on one of two valid dates, sorted by oldest call first.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: also another issue is that the 'TimeOfCall' db column is a 'datetime2(7)' type and the ValidDate1/2 db colums are type 'date'...can I compare these?

With some syntax help :below: I am closer but am getting the following runtime error:

Sequence contains no elements

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Source Error: 


Line 27:         protected void getAllRides()
Line 28:         {
Line 29:             using (RamRideOpsEntities myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
Line 30:             {
Line 31:                 var adminOptions = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions

Source File: D:\DOCUMENTS\RamRide\RamRideOps_PL\RamRideOps\RamRideOps\Ops\DispatchCar.aspx.cs    Line: 29 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +336
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__0(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +150
   System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   RamRideOps.DispatchCar.getNextRide(Int32 carNum) in D:\DOCUMENTS\RamRide\RamRideOps_PL\RamRideOps\RamRideOps\Ops\DispatchCar.aspx.cs:29
   RamRideOps.DispatchCar.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\DOCUMENTS\RamRide\RamRideOps_PL\RamRideOps\RamRideOps\Ops\DispatchCar.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validDate1 and validDate2 will both be Queryable AdminOptions

you probably want this

```
var adminOptions = (from a in myEntities.AdminOptions
                             select new { a.ValidDate1, a.ValidDate2 }).First();
```

Assumes Table with fields ValidDate1 & ValidDate2 (not a propertyBag style with Keys and Values)

now you can get your rides like this

```
var rides = (from r in myEntities.Rides
                           where (r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate1 || 
                                  r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate2)
                           orderby TimeOfCall descending
                           select r).ToList();
```

The ToList() will avoid the need to do a loop at the end to build an array.

That should pretty much fix your syntax.

**EDIT**

I missed putting the r in TimeOfCall in the orderby line

```
var rides = (from r in myEntities.Rides
                           where (r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate1 || 
                                  r.TimeOfCall == adminOptions.ValidDate2)
                           orderby r.TimeOfCall descending
                           select r).ToList();
```

I think you really need to look at doing a few of the tutorials around the place, or buy a good book on the subject. An afternoon of reading might save you a bunch of frustration.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! The only odd thing left is that it tells me that "TimeOfCall does not exist in the current context" ...referring to the 'orderby' statement... not sure why it only has a problem with that one use of "TimeOfCall" and not the others. It should exist. Any thoughts?

Comment: Dang, well it looks like I still have an issue, even when I remove the  orderby statement I get a runtime error (possibly related?) : (error added above ^)

Comment: That runtime error is because nothing is coming back from the first query. I only took a guess at the structure of the AdminOptions table. You'll have to be very clear about its structure before I can help you with it.

Comment: Is there data in the AdminOptions Table?

Comment: Yes there is data in the table, actually the adminoptions part seems fine, its the Rides table that is causing the issue. It is a Microsoft SQL DB server that I am connected to though an EntityDataSource. What information can I provide you with so you can help?

Comment: can you post a diagram of your db schema for these two tables or at least their create scripts and/or small examples of actual row data

Comment: change the .First() to .FirstOrDefault() this will bring back a null if there are no rows coming back from your first query,

Comment: if ValidDate1, ValidDate2, and TimeOfCall are datetime2 there shouldn't be a problem as they all map the .Net's DateTime type. Check that they are the right type on your design surface.